# Excel VBA filter CritiriaRange

Tags: excel, vba, range, advanced-filter

I want to filter 2 columns from my sheet (B and C) and created code to do so but want to make it easier to change the filter criteria.

What I have created is:

```
Sub test()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim Mh As String
Mh = ActiveSheet.Name 'Month name

'Add en Rename ActiveSheet
   Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Test " & Mh

'Filter Ranges
 Range("A1").Select
 Sheets("October").Range("A1:F999").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Filters").Range("A1:B2"), CopyToRange:=Range("A1:F1"), Unique:=False

End Sub
```

What I would like is something like this to be able to change the filternames:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:F999").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="WABO"
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:F999").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Zuid"
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

## Filter Combo

You have a sheet called after a month. You add a new sheet to the last postition and rename it. Now you can refer to it with `Sheets(Sheets.Count)` or `Sheets("Test " & Mh)` or `ActiveSheet`. I chose the first way. Then you copy the specifically filtered range (filters from sheet `Filters`) in the initial sheet to the new sheet. You apply additional 2 filters on the range.

```
Sub test()

  Const cStr2 = "WABO"
  Const cStr3 = "Zuid"

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Dim Mh As String

  Mh = ActiveSheet.Name 'Month name

  'Add and Rename ActiveSheet
  Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Test " & Mh

  With Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    'Filter Ranges
     Sheets(Mh).Range("A1:F999").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
         CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Filters").Range("A1:B2"), _
         CopyToRange:=.Range("A1:F1")
    .Range("A2:F999").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=cStr2
    .Range("A2:F999").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=cStr3
  End With

  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```